# Hue Compatible Wall Switch?

Tags: lighting, switch

I have a bunch of Hue bulbs throughout the house.  Most are controlled via your standard wall switch.   This is, of course, sub-optimal;  with the wall switch off, the Hue lamp can't be remotely controlled.

I'm looking for switch that is, effectively, a power pass through with a signaling mechanism for controlling the Hue.  That would be ideal but, I suspect, runs afoul of electrical code.

**Question:  Is there some device that could *replace the existing wall switches* while still leaving the Hue powered while also providing signaling to turn the Hue off?**

So, the next best solution appears to be using something like the Lutron Caseta switches.   They can be configured to replace the 3 way switches and are Apple HomeKit compatible.

**Is there a Caseta switch that is either just on/off *or* can the Caseta dimmers be configured to not dim?**

Comment: @isherwood Yup;  think about it.  It makes sense.  The Hue needs power all the time which is exactly the opposite of what wall switches do.   So, I need a product that can replace a light switch, be compatible with electrical code, power the Hue at all times, but provide some kind of a signaling mechanism to tell the hue to go off.  **Or** I need a homekit compatible home control product that has a non-dimming simple switch (which is astonishingly hard to find).

Comment: why not just disconnect the switch altogether, and have the wires always connected. You can leave the switch there if you want to be able to sort it at a later date.

Comment: Because I suspect that'll be a code violation.  And I don't want a blank plate.

Answer (score 1):

There are options available.  Maybe they are so new, you just didn't know about them:

[Hue Dimmer Switch](http://www2.meethue.com/en-us/productdetail/philips-hue-dimmer-switch)

[Hue Tap Switch](http://www2.meethue.com/en-us/productdetail/philips-hue-tap-switch)

Comment: Nope;  they don't solve the problem.  Neither of them replace an existing wall switch.

Comment: I doubt anyone is going to make a competing product that a Hue branded product already solves.  Just remove the current switch, twist the wires together and put this on the wall next to it if you _really_ don't like the switch there.  The Lutron dimmers cost twice as much.  I guess I don't get the need to replace the current switches.

Comment: Twist the wires together in wall?  Pretty sure that is against code.  And I don't want an ugly blank face plate or dysfunctional switch.

Comment: Point taken about not wanting the blank plate or useless switch, but twisting wires together in a switch box is done all the time,  Code requires that all wire splices are done in boxes.  Anyway, sounds like you found a workable solution.

Comment: Based on [this image](https://www.macsources.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Photo_118.jpg) of the hue dimmer mounting plate, a blank plate with some strategically placed magnets seems like a good solution.

Comment: I suspect the code violation would be because the ceiling fixture containing the lamp is no longer switched, not the actual twisting of the wires.  Potentially for safety reasons but more likely for energy efficiency reasons (Title 24 and all that -- I'm in CA).

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out.   Buried on the Lutron Caseta website is the full product inventory and they do have a simple switch:

http://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/0301799_WEB.pdf

The only problem with this is that a command to Siri to "turn all lights off" will likely both dim the Hue simultaneously with telling the Caseta to turn off.  There'll be some inconsistency to the behavior.

Looks like PD-5WS-DV is a better solution, actually.